# Google cloud function bigquery json insert TypeError: job.promise is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

[I'm replicating this Google authored tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid#importing_data_into_bigquery) and I have run into a problem and error that I can't figure out how to resolve.

On the Google Cloud Function import json to bigquery, I get an error " TypeError: job.promise is not a function "

Which is located towards the bottom of the function, the code in question is:

```
.then(([job]) => job.promise())
```

[The error led me to this discussion about the API used](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2710), but I don't understand how to resolve the error.

I tried `.then(([ job ]) => waitJobFinish(job))` and removing the line resolves the error but doesn't insert anything.

Tertiary question: I also can't find documentation on how to trigger a test of the function so that I can read my console.logs in the google cloud function console, which would help to figure this out . I can test the json POST part of this function, but I can't find what json to trigger a test of a new file write to cloud storage - the test says must include a bucket but I don't know what json to format (the json I use to test the post -> store to cloud storage doesn't work)

Here is the full function which I've pulled into it's own function:

```
(function () {
   'use strict';


    // Get a reference to the Cloud Storage component
    const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
    // Get a reference to the BigQuery component
    const bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')();


    function getTable () {
      const dataset = bigquery.dataset("iterableToBigquery");

      return dataset.get({ autoCreate: true })
        .then(([dataset]) => dataset.table("iterableToBigquery").get({ autoCreate: true }));
    }


    //set trigger for new files to google storage bucket
    exports.iterableToBigquery = (event) => {
      const file = event.data;

      if (file.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
        // This was a deletion event, we don't want to process this
        return;
      }

      return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
          if (!file.bucket) {
            throw new Error('Bucket not provided. Make sure you have a "bucket" property in your request');
          } else if (!file.name) {
            throw new Error('Filename not provided. Make sure you have a "name" property in your request');
          }

          return getTable();
        })
        .then(([table]) => {
          const fileObj = storage.bucket(file.bucket).file(file.name);
          console.log(`Starting job for ${file.name}`);
          const metadata = {
            autodetect: true,
            sourceFormat: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
          };
          return table.import(fileObj, metadata);
        })
        .then(([job]) => job.promise())
        //.then(([ job ]) => waitJobFinish(job))

        .then(() => console.log(`Job complete for ${file.name}`))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(`Job failed for ${file.name}`);
          return Promise.reject(err);
        });
    };


}());
```

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't figure out how to fix google's example, but I was able to get this load from js to work with the following code in google cloud function:

```
'use strict';
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
// Get a reference to the Cloud Storage component
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
// Get a reference to the BigQuery component
const bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')();

exports.iterableToBigquery = (event) => {
  const file = event.data;

  if (file.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
    // This was a deletion event, we don't want to process this
    return;
  }

    const importmetadata = {
        autodetect: false,
        sourceFormat: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
    };

    let job;

  // Loads data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
  bigquery
    .dataset("analytics")
    .table("iterable")
    .import(storage.bucket(file.bucket).file(file.name),importmetadata)
    .then(results => {
      job = results[0];
      console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

      // Wait for the job to finish
      return job;
    })
    .then(metadata => {
      // Check the job's status for errors
      const errors = metadata.status.errors;
      if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        throw errors;
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });


};
```

Comment: @Dilion Doyle Does `.import()` on `table()` actually work for you?

Comment: @mauricioSanchez yes but the bigquery/google limits on imports is a big big problem. It might work at scale I think if you have giant json files and only import every like 10 minutes. I changed to streaming inserts and just got rid of the concept of kind of using json like this. I got the idea from google's own cloud function examples but it doesn't scale.

Comment: @Dillion Doyle, interesting. I didn't see this in the documentation but I see your point. of streaming vs one block load

Comment: @mauricioSanchez [sorry it is here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid), which I guess isn't documentation but rather an example. It very closely aligns with our use case which is where I found their example in the first place!